# Why bytes of one word has opposite order in binary files?

Tags: binary-data, bmp

I was reading BMP file in hex editor while discovered something odd. Two first letters "BM" are written in order, however the next word(2B), which is means file size, is `36 30` in hex. Actual size is `0x3036`. I've noticed that other numbers are stored the same way.
I'm also using MARS MIPS emulator which can display memory by words. String `in.bmp` is stored as `b . n i` `/ \0 p m`.

Why data isn't stored continuously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends not on the data itself but on how you *store* this data: per byte, per word (2 bytes, usually), or per long (4 bytes -- again, usually). As long as you store data per *byte* you don't see anything unusual; data appears "continuous". However, with longer units, you are subject to [endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926760/the-reason-behind-endianness).

It appears your emulator is *assuming* all words need to have their bytes reversed; and you can see in your example that this assumption is not always valid.

As for the `BM` "magic" signature: it's not meant to be read as a *word* value "BM", but rather as "first, a single byte `B`, then a single byte `M`". All next values are written in [little-endian order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113827/why-is-the-bmp-file-format-stored-in-big-endian), not only 'exchanging' your `36` and `30` but also the 2 zeroes 'before' (or 'after') (the larger values in the [BMP header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930979.aspx) are of 4 bytes `long` type).